# What is the role of variable/term assignment functions in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I was reading through Leary and Kristiansen's *A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, and had some trouble understanding the idea of variable/term assignment functions. The authors give the following definitions:

Given a language $\mathcal{L}$, and an $\mathcal{L}-$structure $\mathfrak{A}$ (whose universe is $A$), a **variable assignment function** is a map $s$ from the set of variables to A. Furthermore, a **term assignment function** is a function $\overline{s}$ mapping the set of $\mathcal{L}-$terms into $A$, such that:

(1) if $t$ is a variable, then $\overline{s}(t) = s(t)$

(2) if $t$ is a constant symbol $c$, then $\overline{s}(t) = c^{\mathfrak{A}}$

(3) if $t := ft_{1}t_{2}...t_{n}$, then $\overline{s}(t) = f^{\mathfrak{A}}(\overline{s}(t_{1}), \overline{s}(t_{2}), ..., \overline{s}(t_{n}))$.

My question is what these variable and term assignment functions are supposed to represent. My initial impression is that they are supposed to represent ways of interpreting variables. For example, if $\mathcal{L}_{NT} = \{0, S, +, \cdot, E, <\}$ is the language of number theory, and we're talking about its standard structure $\mathfrak{N} = \{\mathbb{N}, 0, S, +, \cdot, E, <\}$, then the formula $x=y$ may or may not be true, depending on what we "decide" $x$ and $y$ stand for. If we're talking about a variable assignment function where $s(x) = 1$ and $s(y) = 2$, then the formula will be false. But if $s(x) = 1$ and $s(y) = 1$, then the formula will be true. So it seems to me that these assignment functions are meant to realize a particular choice of what each variable represents, so that we can talk about the truth of formulas involving these variables.

Is this assessment correct?

Comment: Your conclusion about truth or falsity of interpreted $x=y$ statement are OK. But keep in mind in general the function symbols in the language may have *any* function of the same arity on the target universe as interpretation.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? I don't understand what you mean by "function symbols may have any function of the same arity as the interpretation."

Comment: In statement (3) of the quoted definition of variable assignment there is a reference to $ft_1t_2...t_n$ which means $f$ is a "function symbol" of the language of "arity" $n.$ [note "arity" just means how many arguments the function symbol takes.] The interpretation is labelled $f$ with an upper fancy script U on it, meaning a function from the $n$-fold cartesian product of the universe $U$ into $U.$

Comment: Your description of the purpose of variable-assignments is correct. The basic idea is that, for formulas and terms to have meanings (values of terms and truth values of formulas), one needs meanings for all the symbols in them.  For some symbols (like connectives) the meaning is fixed once and for all. For other symbols, the meaning is given by a structure. And for variables, the value is given by an assignment.

Comment: @coffeemath  $\mathfrak A$ is a Fraktur A.  A Fraktur U looks like $\mathfrak U$.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now. Thank you all <3

Comment: @AndreasBlass I just tried a few combinations of "A Fractur U" between dollar signs, some with the slash before the U, some with the braces around the U, some with just Frac, etc. but none worked in mathjax.

Comment: @coffeemath The command for Fraktur font is \mathfrak, so if you write "\mathfrak A" or "\mathfrak U" (without the quotation marks) between dollar signs, it should work.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That worked -- thanks.